# Как бороться с утечкой памяти при экспорте данных в Yii2?

Tags: php, yii2, pdo, activerecord

Делаю экспорт в CSV относительно `dataProvider`. Но получается, что в какой-то момент на сложной `view` (более 10 `join`) падает с ошибкой о нехватке памяти PDO.

Код:

```php
private function writeContentRowsQuery() {
    $offset = 0;
    
    while ($queryResult = $this->dataProvider->query->limit($this->_settings['limit'])->offset($offset)->createCommand()->queryAll()) {
        foreach ($queryResult as $row) {
            $rowData = [];
            
            foreach ($this->_visibleColumns as $visibleColumn) {
                $rowData[] = $this->getDataCellQueryValue($visibleColumn, $row);
            }
            
            fputcsv($this->_csv, $rowData, ';');
            ob_flush();
            flush();
            
            unset($rowData);
            gc_collect_cycles();
        }
        
        $offset += $this->_settings['limit'];
        
        unset($queryResult);
        gc_collect_cycles();
    }
    
    gc_collect_cycles();
}
```

Здесь идет инициализация процесса так:

```php
ob_start();
$this->_csv = fopen('php://output', 'wb');

if (!empty($this->contentBefore)) {
    $this->writeBeforeContentRows();
}

$this->writeColumnHeaders();
$this->writeContentRowsQuery();
fclose($this->_csv);
```

Что делать в таком случае?

Ошибки:
PDOException: SQLSTATE[54000]: Program limit exceeded: 7 ОШИБКА:  нехватка памяти
DETAIL:  Не удалось увеличить строковый буфер

Орет на строки:

1. `ob_flush();` о том, что Headers already sent
2. `while ($queryResult = $this->dataProvider->query->limit($this->_settings['limit'])->offset($offset)->createCommand()->queryAll())` о нехватке памяти

Comment: Попробуй генератором строки забрать из базы.

Comment: Может лимиты поубавить? У меня на 2000 строк работает без всяких ob_* и collect_*. Может еще что-то тяжелое в $this->getDataCellQueryValue?

Comment: @fedornabilkin прочитал на форумах, говорят надо отключить кеширование запросов в БД на эту операцию. `getDataCellQueryValue` просто выполняет получение данных без моделей и так далее. Висит все дело на запросе этом. Учитывая, что я вычищаю каждый раз все.... Странно. А про какой генератор строки вы говорите?

Comment: Не генератор строки. А забрать строки из БД с использованием генератора. Он делает конский запрос, но данные не держит в памяти, а хранит указатель. Правда можно БД уложить, если слишком много данных будет. Для такого реплики делают. Можно тут глянуть, очень доходчиво https://folkprog.net/ispol-zovaniie-php-generatorov/

Comment: @fedornabilkin я прочитал про них. Что-то не до конца понял как работать с ними в моей задаче) Можно небольшой пример с бд?