# Почему приходит лишь часть файла?

Tags: php, qt, qt5, php7

Есть код скачивания файла:

```
QNetworkAccessManager nam;
nam.setRedirectPolicy(QNetworkRequest::NoLessSafeRedirectPolicy);
QNetworkRequest req(QUrl("https://slimpage.ru/DWAKU2_updater.php"));
req.setRawHeader("Content-Type","multipart/form-data; boundary=margin");
QByteArray data = ("--margin\r\n");
data.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"download_latest\"\r\n\r\n\r\n");
data.append("--margin--\r\n");
QNetworkReply *reply = nam.post(req, data);
QEventLoop loop;
QObject::connect(reply, SIGNAL(readyRead()), &loop, SLOT(quit()));
QObject::connect(&nam, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)), &loop, SLOT(quit()));
if (!reply->isFinished()) loop.exec();
QSaveFile file(QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath() + QDir::separator() + "latest_DWAKU2.exe");
file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
qDebug() << reply->size();
file.write(reply->readAll());
file.commit();
nam.deleteLater();
delete reply;
```

Есть код PHP:

```
<?php
$dir = '/SlimPage/www/DWAKU2';

function file_force_download($file) {
  if (file_exists($file)) {
    // сбрасываем буфер вывода PHP, чтобы избежать переполнения памяти выделенной под скрипт
    // если этого не сделать файл будет читаться в память полностью!
    if (ob_get_level()) {
      ob_end_clean();
    }
    // заставляем браузер показать окно сохранения файла
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . basename($file));
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    // читаем файл и отправляем его пользователю
    readfile($file);
  }
}

// GET запросы
if (!empty($_GET)) {

    // Проверка доступности сервера
    if(isset($_GET['ping'])) {  
        echo 'pong';
        exit;
    } else

    // Получить версию для обновления
    if(isset($_GET['get_latest_version'])) {
        $files = array();
        foreach(glob($dir . '/*') as $file) {   
            if (is_file($file)) {
                if (pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION) == 'exe')
                $files[] = basename(pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_FILENAME));    
            }
        } 
        echo array_pop($files);
        exit;
    }       
}

// POST запросы
if (!empty($_POST)) {
    
    // Загрузка новой версии
    if(isset($_POST['download_latest'])) {
        $files = array();
        foreach(glob($dir . '/*') as $file) {   
            if (is_file($file)) {
                if (pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION) == 'exe')
                    $files[] = $file;                   
            }
        } 
        file_force_download(array_pop($files));
        exit;
    }   
}
    

?>
```

Файл размером 6.03 Mb, а скачивается по POST запросу всего 48 Kb

Можете подсказать, как это исправить?

Comment: Попробуйте использовать `stream`. Я как-то работал с похожим: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1221859/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%80%d0%be%d1%82%d1%8c%d1%81%d1%8f-%d1%81-%d1%83%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%87%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%bc%d1%8f%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d1%8d%d0%ba%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b5-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%b2-yii2

Comment: @mepihindeveloper можете привести код?

Comment: я указал ссылку на свой вопрос с кодом

Comment: @mepihindeveloper там php код. НО! Если посмотреть через Fiddler - сервер отдает весь файл. Здесь скорее проблема в QT/C++ коде

Comment: @mepihindeveloper и я пытаюсь найти эту проблему.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как видим, файл большой.
Сервер передает его частями, а QReply получает его частями.
Важно заметить, что `isFinished()` наступает, когда получена **первая** часть.
Вот и получаем, что скачивается только первая часть, отданная сервером.
Чтобы получить весь файл - нам нужно или скачивать по частям, сверяя полученный размер байтов с итоговым, или сделать проверку на получение всего файла:

```
while (reply->isRunning()) loop.exec();
```